# Did Surak and his followers get naked, covered in grease and chase each other around?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I'm trying to understand the timeline of the celebration of ***Rumarie*** among Vulcans in relation to the the rejection of emotion to follow logic and Surak's other teaching.

It's hard to imagine Surak, his followers, and later somberly logic Vulcans taking off their clothes, greasing themselves up with Rillan grease, and chasing each other around. These weren't exactly primitive times on Vulcan either - they already had nuclear weapons and interstellar travel.

However, on the *Voyager* episode *[Meld](http://www.voyager.cz/voyager/epizody/32meldtrans.htm)*, Tuvoc told Neelix this holiday was celebrated as such until 1,000 years ago. My research on Wikipedia and Alpha Memory seems to indicate that Surak lived 1,800 - 2,000 years prior, thus Surak and Vulcans for 1,000 years after his teaching still observed the customs of Rumarie?

If so, perhaps an explaination of the logic is in order.

Alpha Memory:

> Rumarie was an ancient pagan festival on the planet Vulcan that was
>   last observed during the 14th century AD.
>
> In 2372, while learning about Vulcan holidays, Neelix discovered
>   Rumarie, which he described as a festival "full of barely clothed
>   Vulcan men and women, covered in slippery Rillan grease, chasing one
>   another." (VOY: "Meld")

Comment: Would a picture help? http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/1/1b/Surak.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150807082551&path-prefix=en

Comment: @Valorum hehe. Yea but on TOS he looked a lot more spry than that. Not to mention, there are some freaky old people. See the look in his eye? http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/0/02/Surak_jung.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120517182653&path-prefix=de

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Memory Alpha, Surak's teachings were not instantly accepted. The [Time of Awakening](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Time_of_Awakening) took 1,500 years. If it started in the Earth 4th century AD, that means would not be complete until the 19th century.

[Rumarie was an ancient pagan festival on the planet Vulcan that was last observed during the 14th century AD.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rumarie) **So it's possible that it was still being celebrated by people who had not yet converted to Surak's philosophy.** And maybe some converts even thought it would be logical to continue celebrating for some reason.

As for whether Surak personally participated in Rumarie celebrations, we don't know for sure (but I'm guessing he didn't). Just because it's a Vulcan holiday doesn't mean every single Vulcan participates. After all, Christmas has become a holiday celebrated all over Earth, but we celebrate in different ways and many people don't celebrate it at all.